# SQL Triggers using multiple tables

Tags: sql, triggers

**Question**

Write an SQL command to create a trigger in table Order. The trigger should subtract the quantity of a product in an order from the quantityRemaining column in the table Product, after each time that product appears in a new order row in table Order.

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
productNo int PRIMARY KEY,
productName VARCHAR(30),
quantityRemaining INT,
cost DECIMAL (10,2) DEFAULT 0.00);

CREATE TABLE Orders(
orderNo INT PRIMARY KEY,
custNo INT CONSTRAINT cusNo_fk REFERENCES CustomerDetails(custNo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
productNo INT CONSTRAINT prodNo_fk REFERENCES Product(productNo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
quantity INT);
```

**Attempt**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER subtractQuantity 
AFTER INSERT ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
     UPDATE Product
     SET quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining - quantity
     WHERE productNo = :NEW.ProductNo;
END;
/
```

**Error**

it doesn't recognise the 'quantity' variable.

Comment: that's because it's in Orders not table Product

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing `:New.` for the reference:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER subtractQuantity 
AFTER INSERT ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
     UPDATE Product
     SET quantityRemaining = quantityRemaining - :NEW.quantity
     WHERE productNo = :NEW.ProductNo;
END;
```

`quantity` is in the `Orders` table, not the `Product` table.

Comment: thank you soo much it worked. would accept this as answer but doesn't let me cuz of the reputation thing but thannks anyways :)

Comment: @user2993831: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.